# Record all the steps and outputs of command prompt

Tags: file, command-prompt

I am running a program on command prompt. There are several outputs in the command prompt as I go on running the program. Is there a single way to record all the steps and outputs in command prompt and dump it to a file?

```
command > dump.txt
```

The above command only works for a single step. Not for the entire outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one that I have found upto this point is:

```
command >> dump.txt
```

The problem with this command is, it only allows output to run on the file, not on command prompt itself.